# Python exceptions in core files while using Jython, Weblogic, modjy

Tags: django, weblogic, jython

This is the first time I'm trying to run a Django app on top of Jython, using Weblogic and modjy.

I've installed locally Jython 2.5.3, and I'm able to run my Django application using the dev server (jython manage.py runserver) without glitches.

I'm on OSX 10.7.4 and these are my Java info:

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

Then I tried to deploy the app in WebLogic. I've used the django-jython package to generate the WAR file. When I try to deploy it using the WebLogic web console, I get the following exception when it tries to startup the app:

> Servlet: "modjy" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "bbb". Traceback (innermost last): File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 421, in ? File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 402, in main File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 92, in removeduppaths NameError: set :org.python.core.PyException:null

This is the expanded WAR file I'm trying to deploy: http://www.2shared.com/file/aec-0BR8/bbb.html

So the weird error seems to be inside a core python module (site.py). I went inside this file, expanding the WAR file, and I "fixed" it (just to see what happened next) by doing

```
from sets import Set as set
```

at line 92 in `WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py`

This lead to another error:

> [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "modjy" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "bbb". Traceback (innermost last): File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 422, in ? File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 403, in main File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 98, in removeduppaths File "/Users/fabio/weblogic/novartis/servers/myserver/stage/bbb/bbb/WEB-INF/lib-python/Lib/site.py", line 68, in makepath AttributeError: class 'org.python.modules.os' has no attribute 'path' :org.python.core.PyException:null

Again, related to a core python module.
It should be noted that if I try to remove the jython.jar file inside `WEB-INF/lib/jython.jar` I don't get any error, while I was expecting it to be referenced when deploying the WAR file.

Thanks for any input on this.